# Entity Framework - multiple foreign keys to same table causing data to be updated incorrectly

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following 2 tables in my database:

**Address**:

```
Street1
City
State
Zipcode
```

**Customers**:

```
Name
LocationAddressId (FK to Address table)
MailingAddressId (FK to address table)
```

I generated an Entity Framework model for this. When I create a customer object and populate only `LocationAddress` but not `MailingAddress`, an id (primary key for address table) is generated for `LocationAddress`. This id is assigned to `LocationAddressId` and the same id is being assigned to `MailingAddressId` as well.

Here is the code I have:

```
 Customer c = new Customer();
 var a = new Address
 {
        Street1 = "Test",
        City = "test",
        Zip = "43343",
        Country = "sdf",
 };

 c.Address = a;
 c.Name = "Test Customer";

 ctx.Customers.AddObject(c);
 ctx.SaveChanges();
```

After I save the changes, `c.LocationAddressId` and `c.MailingAddressId` are the same even though I didn't assign anything to Mailing Address.

Problem #2:

In my code, when I try to create `MailingAddress` as well, I get the error

> "Unable to determine the principal end of the
>   'TestModel.FK_Customer_LocationAddress_Address' relationship. Multiple
>   added entities may have the same primary key.

This is my code:

```
  Customer c = new Customer();
  var a = new Address
  {
        Street1 = "Test",
        City = "test",
        Zip = "43343",
        Country = "sdf",
  };

  c.Address = a;

  var b = new Address
  {
        Street1 = "Test mailing addr",
        City = "test",
        Zip = "43343",
        Country = "sdf",
  };

  c.Address1 = b;
  c.Name = "Test Customer";

  ctx.Customers.AddObject(c);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I am not sure if I am creating the objects the right way. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing the issues?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion to start: take the foreign keys out of the customer table, create an address type in the address table, add the customer as a foreign key to the address table. This creates a many to one relationship between addresses and customers. i.e. customer has 2 stored addresses: a MAILING and PHYSICAL type. This allows you to add new address types if needed, e.g. SHIPPING, without needing another column. When that works, then work out how to do a many to many relationship (using a junction table) as more than one customer may live at the same address. Better DB design is easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please note that customers is not the only table in my database refering to address table. There are a ton of other tables referencing address table.